# Passing data to Fragment before destroying Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, android-lifecycle

I've

**Activity A -> Fragment A**

[from `Fragment A` I decide to create `Activity B`]

**Fragment A ->  Activity B**.

When I press back button, I go back to `Fragment A` which contains data list. I'd like to update this list when back button is pressed. No, I don't store data locally and making another request is too expensive. Is there a simple way to pass modified object X on back button press [From Activity B to Fragment A]? How?

Comment: Use `BroadcastReceiver` for your case

Comment: Of course, you can use BroadcastReceiver and also start startActivityForResult()

Comment: Use interface as a callback and call its method when onBackPressed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fragment A you can call a method from Activity A to start an activity with result to Activity B.

When you go back you can send that data with it.
In activity A you can have the method onActivityResult to catch this result and refresh Fragment A.

[Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#java)